# Passing parameter in a Ruby function from HTML

Tags: html, ruby, function, rhodes

I have two files. **.rb** (with Ruby code) and **.erb**(HTML file with some ruby script). I am calling a Ruby function in **.rb** from **.erb**.

**.erb**

```
<a href="<%= url_for :action => :showProducts(i) %>">Click here</a>
```

**.rb**

```
def showProducts(param)

//Some code

end
```

I am able to call a function without passing parameters to it. But as and when I pass parameters to function and then call it, I receive an error. I know this is the incorrect way to call a parametrized function from **.erb**. What is the correct way of calling a parameterized function from HTML?

Comment: Looks like your syntax is correct. What's not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: It just comes as "Error loading page."

Comment: Then you'll find more details in the log. What does that say?

Comment: When I try debugging, control doesn't go inside the function. (I tried with solution below but still no success).

Comment: Yes, and as I asked in the previous question, what does the *log* say? Not the debugger -- the *log*?

Comment: Nothing at all? Do you at least see Rails receiving the request?

Comment: @Marnen : Please check my answer. I found the solution.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Silly me. I thought you had said this was a Rails application. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem :

```
<a href="<%= url_for :action => :showProducts, :id=> 'Hello' %>">
```

.rb function:

```
def showProducts(param)

//Some code

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add in another key/value pair to the hash in `url_for`

```
<%= url_for :action => :showProducts, :product => "toaster" %>
```

Your URL should go from, say, `http://localhost:3000/showProducts` to `http://localhost:3000/showProducts?product=toaster`

Here, we're adding parameters to the GET request. To access these parameters in the controller we use the `params` hash. For example to get the `product` (`toaster`):

```
params[:product] #=> "toaster"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
def showProducts 

 @params['product']

end
```